# Equivalence of prior alternatives

Tags: bayesian

Suppose I have Bernoulli distribution with (p) parameter. Suppose I assume a uniform prior over this parameter. My question is, would this be equivalent to assuming a Beta prior, and then **uniform** alpha and beta as hyper-priors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For them to be equal, $$f(p)=\int_a\int_bf(p|\alpha,\beta)f(\alpha)f(\beta)d\alpha d\beta$$ should be uniform PDF for $p$. Note that you haven't specified ranges for $a$ and $b$, but let's assume they have equal ranges and they're independent. I feel this integral is hard (and maybe intractable) to calculate so simply, their moments should be equivalent. From uniform distribution, we know that $E[p]=1/2$ and $E[p^2]=1/3$. Using the second formulation and the law of iterated expectations, we have
$$E[p]=E[E[p|\alpha,\beta]]=E\left[\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\right]$$
which is really $1/2$ due to symmetry. Evaluating the second moment yields:

$$E[p^2]=E[E[p^2|\alpha,\beta]]=E\left[\frac{(\alpha+1)\alpha}{(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha+\beta+1)}\right]$$
which can be quite cumbersome to calculate but possible. However, I prefer to informally pose experimental evidence to show that this is not equal to $1/3$ via a couple of Python lines:

```
N = 10000
a = np.random.random(N)
b = np.random.random(N)
print(np.mean( (a+1)*a / ((a+b)*(a+b+1)) ))
```

Output:

```
0.4041670326640888
```

which also changes with respect to the ranges of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, while $E[p]$ doesn't. Here, the range is $[0,1]$. If we expand the range to $+\infty$, I see that this number is nearly $0.3$. At some point in between, an equivalence might or might not be possible but it needs to be shown analytically. In the end, beta distribution is uniform when $\alpha=\beta=1$, and a suitable range *might* (or not) emulate it. Nevertheless, the general equivalence is not an issue.